# Xcode will not accept user input!

Tags: xcode, user-input

my xcode will compile but not let me input anything

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool truthStatement;
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string name;
    cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    if (name == "Matt"){
        cout << "You're cool" << endl;

    } else {
        cout << "You suck" << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?  Just tried a test project in XCode.  Seems to work fine.

Comment: Has your question been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before.  Make sure you are using the Return key and not the Enter key on the keyboard.